# Typescript Union Types: Dealing with Interfaces

Tags: typescript

What's the proper way to handle a situation where you have two interfaces that are similar enough that you want to run them through the same piece of logic:

```
interface DescriptionItem {
    Description: string;
    Code: string;
}
interface NamedItem {
    Name: string;
    Code: string;
}

function MyLogic(i: DescriptionItem | NamedItem) {
    var desc = (<DescriptionItem>i).Description || (<NamedItem>i).Name;

    return i.Code + ' - ' + desc;
}
```

This works; however, my question is on improving the `var desc = ...` line.  Is what I have above the best option?  Or is there a better way to handle this situation in Typescript?

Comment: I would say the way you did it looks fine. However the question itself is primarily opinion based and I'll vote to close it on that basis. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TypeScript `interfaces` only exist at compile-time, so there isn't much you can do to test for interface types at run-time.  The code you specified in your question makes sense and is probably your best option.

However, if you have the flexibility to change your `interfaces` to `classes`, you can use TypeScript's type guards to do more elegant type checking:

```
class DescriptionItem {
    Description: string;
    Code: string;
}
class NamedItem {
    Name: string;
    Code: string;
}

function MyLogic(i: DescriptionItem | NamedItem) {
    let desc: string;
    if (i instanceof DescriptionItem) {
        desc = i.Description;
    } else {
        desc = i.Name;
    }

    return i.Code + ' - ' + desc;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you check if `i.Name` exists and differentiate the types based on that?

Comment: @jocull What if the object was an instance of `NamedItem`, but its `Name` was `undefined`?

Comment: If it's missing non-optional data, is it really an instance of `NamedItem` then?

Comment: @jocull I suppose that depends on your use case.

Comment: are there any downsides of using classes over interfaces? This is probably the best solution I found around differentiating types in typescript.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is very old, but I was playing around with the same problem, as I was learning the difference between | and & when making Type Unions.

there are some options to solve this problem (that is also linter-friendly).
The best way is to use a discriminator in all your interfaces (a [narrow interface](https://medium.com/@OlegVaraksin/narrow-interfaces-in-typescript-5dadbce7b463)).

```
//First create a super-interface that have the discriminator
interface B
{
    kind:'b1'|'b2' //define discriminator with all the posible values as string-literals (this is where the magic is)
}

interface B1 extends B
{
    kind: 'b1' //now narrow the inherited interfaces literals down to a single 
    //after that add your interface specific fields
    data1: string;
    data: string;
}

interface B2 extends B
{
    kind:'b2' //now narrow the inherited interfaces literals down to a single
    //after that add your interface specific fields
    data2: string;
    data: string;
}

//lets initialize 1 B1 type by using the literal value of a B1 interface 'b1'
var b1: B1|B2 = {
    kind:'b1',
    data: 'Hello From Data',
    data1:'Hello From Data1'
    //typescript will not allow you to set data2 as this present a B1 interface
}
//and a B2 Type with the kind 'b2'
var b2: B1|B2 = {
    kind: 'b2',
    data: 'Hello From Data',
    //typescript will not allow you to set data1 as this present a B2 interface
    data2: 'Hello From Data2'
}
```

another option is to check for fields on an object using the ["in"-keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator), but this can cause a lot of boilerplate code, as you have to update it every time you change your interface.

```
interface B1
{
    data1: string;
    data: string;
}

interface B2
{
    data2: string;
    data: string;
}

var b3: B1|B2 = {
    data: 'Hello From Data',
    data1:'Hello From Data1',
    data2:'Hello From Data2'
}

console.log(b3.data); //this field is common in both interfaces and does not need a check

if('data1' in b3) //check if 'data1' is on object
{
    console.log(b3.data1);
}
if('data2' in b3){
    console.log(b3.data2); //check if 'data2' is on object
}
```